# How to read data from Azure Marketplace Fixed query with Windows Store app?

Tags: c#, azure, taskfactory, azure-marketplace

I have this code to call the Service and I get the following error.

```
    Uri serviceUri = new Uri("https://api.datamarket.azure.com/miosoft/coordinate-distance-calculator/v1/");
                    CoordinateDistance context = new CoordinateDistance(serviceUri);
                    context.IgnoreMissingProperties = true;
                    context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxx@outlook.com", "xxx");

                    IEnumerable<Distance> nquery;

                    nquery = context.CoordinateDistanceServiceMethod(-122.347938, 47.637933, -122, 47);
```

This target framework does not enable you to directly enumerate over a data service query. This is because enumeration automatically sends a synchronous request to the data service. Because this framework only supports asynchronous operations, you must instead call the BeginExecute and EndExecute methods to 
obtain a query result that supports enumeration.

So I found code that explained how to call this the right way so I added this code here

```
  DataServiceQuery<Distance> query = (DataServiceQuery<Distance>)nquery;
                    TaskFactory<IEnumerable<Distance>> taskFactory = new TaskFactory<IEnumerable<Distance>>();
                    IEnumerable<Distance> result = await taskFactory.FromAsync(query.BeginExecute(null, null), iar => query.EndExecute(iar));
```

But now on the final Line I get Invalid Parameters.

Any idea ? Or working samples to call a Azure Marketplace fixed query with a Windows Store App ?

Comment: "I get Invalid Parameters" What exactly is the error you're getting? Is it a compile-time error or an exception?

Comment: It is runtime. I heard they are doing a overhaul on the entire marketplace so maybe there will be working code samples in the future. Unless I can figure out how to do that fixed query I have to just use other sources